# Improving, that's my key!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

> Improving, improving, 
>   that's my key!
>
> But then, you have to know, 
>  
>   to which lock it will be!
>
> I tell you this: Images never miss.

I'm leaving this note here so that I won't forget where I left my treasure.

The question, if not obvious: Where did I leave my treasure?

Comment: I've downvoted this question because it relies on a trick in the Stack Exchange format (HTML comments) that I don't think should be used to hold answers to questions. In my opinion, a textual riddle shouldn't lose meaning or solvability if it were printed out on actual paper.

Comment: This gimmick has been used several times in puzzles before.

Comment: I did not DV because there are worse puzzles in comparison but I do agree with our two mods above. Please no more of this kind. It so easily sparks a series of "me too" puzzles of a kind we do not really want to encourage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left your treasure

> on your attic, according to https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lnip2.png ; `Lnip2` is hidden in your post in a comment.

Comment: I had hoped that this would be a little harder. Well done!